# Displaying top bar across view controllers

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, viewcontroller

I have a slide-out menu. When user taps on a button, it is supposed to bring up a view controller specified by the button:

```
case "Something":
    let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Something")! as SomeController
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

However, this method doesn't keep my top bar (*top* bar, not *navigation* bar or *status* bar). It also doesn't swap view controllers, but places one on top of the other. How should this be done?

Top bar will always contain only 'Menu' button which opens a slide-out menu from the left side and a title.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Screenshots would definitely help..

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with view controller containment. Then the parent view controller can change the child view controller by removing the old child and adding a new one. If you want to animate that transition, you can use `transitionFromViewController`. Just make sure to do the necessary containment related calls as outlined in the [Creating Custom Container View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6) discussion.